# Как заменить дни недели на простые числа от 1 до 31 в коде, данным гуглом

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

у меня задача заменить дни недели, которые находят внизу на числа от 1 до 31. Я попытался скачать сам код вот тут
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#controlling-the-colors и в коде изменить дни недели на числа, но скрипт мешает. Может кто знает, как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю это вам поможет

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline-tooltip');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  
  
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Label' });  
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'Name' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'Test', 'Name', new Date(2020, 00, 01), new Date(2020, 00, 31) ]
    ]);

  var options = {
        hAxis: {
          format: 'd' // 'M/d/yy'
        }
      };
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline-tooltip" style="height: 180px;"></div>
```

Comment: Это помогло, но не показываются первое и последнее число(то есть числа начинаются с 2 до 30)

Comment: Это уже сам конрол. Добавите ещё месяц так он вообще половину цифр удалит

Comment: ладно, спасибо.

Comment: Еслт ответ помог то галочка под стрелками